# How can I save image path in database and append that image on the browser in ROR

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Can anybody give me the idea about saving image in the database and show that image on the browser afterwards. I have already some code and name is stored on the database but path can not. Please help me to reedit the code and successfully show the image on the browser.

My code snippets:

views/images/index.html.erb

```
<h1>IMAGE UPLOAD</h1>
<%= form_for @user,:url => {:action => 'save'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name,placeholder:"Enter your name" %>
  Upload your file:<%= f.file_field("uploaded_file") %>
  <%= f.submit "Save"%>
<% end %>
```

views/images/show.html.erb

```
<h3><%= @user.name %></h3>
<img src="<%= url_for(:action => 'file', :id => @user.id) %>"/>
```

controller/images_controller.rb

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user=User.new
  end
  def save
    @user=User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to(action: 'show', id: @user.id)
    else
      render(action: 'index')
    end
  end
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
  def file
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    send_data(@user.data,
      filename: @user.name,
      disposition: "inline")
  end
private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :data)
  end
end
```

model/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def uploaded_file=(file_field)
    self.name = base_part_of(file_field.original_filename)
    self.data = file_field.read
  end
  def base_part_of(file_name)
    File.basename(file_name).gsub(/[^\w._-]/, '')
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'images#index'
  post 'images/save' => 'images#save'
  get 'images/show' => 'images#show'
  get 'images/file' => 'images#file'
end
```

migrate/20141224051228_create_users.rb

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.binary :data

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Please help me to find proper output.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you use paperclip or carrierwave to upload your images ? 
And what do you mean by append image in the browser ? do you mean you want to show the image in a div or something ?

Comment: hello,Pamio solanky you are right.i want to  fetched that image from database and show on the broswer.

Comment: Okay and where are you storing the uploaded files ? I mean which directory ?

Comment: Pamio,i want to store images inside the public directory and saved image path inside database.when user will click on save button that uploaded image should show on the browser.see the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there but you have to make certain changes. I would also suggest you to use `paperclip` - (could be found here [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)) for the file uploads as it provides handy methods for validations and file formats and also that you can crop the images without having to write the code to process the images.

Having said that, for the existing code to work, you have to make some changes.

Change the model to look like this also introduce another field called `image_url`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def uploaded_file=(file_field)
    self.name = base_part_of(file_field.original_filename)
    self.data = file_field.read
    self.image_url = Rails.root + "/public/uploads/" + self.name
  end

  def base_part_of(file_name)
    File.basename(file_name).gsub(/[^\w._-]/, '')
  end
end
```

Now in your views, you could do this

```
<img src="<%= @user.image_url %>"/> and it should work just fine.
```

These are just suggestion and the code is not tested. Hope you get the idea

Comment: Pamio,My doubt was also save image path in database.as per you how can i assign image path value to image_url. please try to run the above code and give me some idea.

Comment: This line `self.image_url = Rails.root + "/public/uploads/" + self.name` already does what you want. Im not sure what ur question is.

Comment: actually i wanted when user will choose image from local system and click on save button the name and image path will save inside the db.after saving if user wants to show the image ,this line <img src="<%= @user.image_url %>"/> will excute and the image will display on the browser.

Comment: What does the code above do ?? I guess it does that. You have to work it out @subhra. If you don't want to does it all by urself then use paperclip please. That will take the border off you. have you even tried the code ?